# Extracting relevant information from poorly-designed database

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I have a database that contains records of thousands of samples analyzed by scientific instrumentation. I need to pull some specific data from it.

For example, my database looks a little like this:

```
ID     Time     SensorValue
---------------------------
aaaa   1        xxxx
aaaa   2        xxxx
aaaa   3        xxxx
bbbb   1        xxxx
bbbb   2        xxxx
bbbb   3        xxxx
bbbb   4        xxxx
cccc   1        xxxx
cccc   2        xxxx
cccc   3        xxxx
cccc   4        xxxx
dddd   1        xxxx
eeee   1        xxxx
eeee   2        xxxx
eeee   3        xxxx
eeee   4        xxxx
eeee   5        xxxx
```

And so on. There are thousands of unique IDs. Time is not always constant. Some analyses take 500 seconds, some take 5000.

What I need is to be able to find the sensor value of a sample at the last time step of a run, be it 500 or 5000. If I only had 10 or 20 samples I would just do it by hand, but since I have thousands, I need to automate it.

Can someone please help with a query to extract this information? I want my result to look like this (assuming the same input as above):

```
ID     Time     SensorValue
---------------------------
aaaa   3        xxxx
bbbb   4        xxxx
cccc   4        xxxx
dddd   1        xxxx
eeee   5        xxxx
```

Answer (score 1):

Join the table to the result of a subquery that find the last time for each ID:

```
select d.*
from (select ID, max(Time) last
      from data_table
      group by ID) t
join data_table d on t.ID = d.ID
  and d.Time = t.last
```

Comment: I tried this and I got "syntax error in FROM clause".

Answer (score 0):

I cannot comment on the first answer, but I'm duplicating the answer here, you need to name the realnameofyourtable with the real name of your table.

`SELECT realnameofyourtable.id, realnameofyourtable.[time], realnameofyourtable.sensorvalue
 FROM realnameofyourtable 
 INNER JOIN (
             SELECT ID, max(time) as timedata 
             FROM realnameofyourtable 
             GROUP BY ID)  AS lastid
 ON (realnameofyourtable.[time] = lastid.timedata) 
 AND (realnameofyourtable.id = lastid.id)`

Comment: Trying this, I get "JOIN expression not supported".

Comment: Sorry about that... did not parse the answer through Access, give it a try now... remember to place in the real name of yout table.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to find the latest time:

```
Select ID, Time, SensorValue
From YourTable
Where Time In
    (Select Max(Time) 
    From YourTable As T
    Where T.ID = YourTable.ID)
```